# windows phone bing maps crashing

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, bing-maps

My app crashes in the emulator when u load the map and then move the map and zoom in instantly. ive tried many different soulutions i found on the internet as the only error i get is Catastrophic Failure and no further information (no line number or any error information whatsoever)

C# code

```
public sealed partial class MapView : MvxWindowsPage
    {
    double lat=0;
    double lon=0;
    Geolocator gl = new Geolocator();
    MapIcon Micon = new MapIcon();
    Geopoint blo;

    public MapView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;


        GetInitialPosition();
    }
    private MapViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return DataContext as MapViewModel; }
    }

    private bool HasViewModel { get { return ViewModel != null; } }
    void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        ViewModel.NavigateFirst();
    }

    async void GetInitialPosition()
    {

        gl.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 500;

        gl.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.Default;

        IAsyncOperation<Geoposition> locationTask = null;

        try
        {
            Geoposition gp = await gl.GetGeopositionAsync(
                maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
                );

            //LatitudeTextBlock.Text = geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00");
            //LongitudeTextBlock.Text = geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00");
        }
        finally
        {
            DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
            dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
            dt.Tick += (sender, e) => ProgBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            dt.Tick += (sender, e) => ProgBar.IsEnabled = false;
            dt.Start();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Xaml:

```
<views:MvxWindowsPage 
xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps" 
x:Class="Etgarim.Views.MapView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Etgarim.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:views="using:Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <Maps:MapControl x:Name="OmNaMap" MapServiceToken="..."/>
    <!--Visibility="Visible" Center="{Binding blo}"-->
    <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgBar" Height="667"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the map control and the progress bar so they not over lapping, this should resolve the issue.

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="667"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ProgressBar Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ProgBar" />
        <Maps:MapControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="OmNaMap" MapServiceToken="..."/>
        <!--Visibility="Visible" Center="{Binding blo}"-->

    </Grid>
```